# Debt collection payment

Tags: debt-collection

In 2016, I rented a apartment for my then boyfriend.I was living at my parent's house and only stayed at that apartment from time to time.Long Story short, he failed to pay one month rent, I got scared so I told the leasing office that I wasn't living there so they kicked him out.In 2017 they sent my account to collections Now the debt $3740 is 3 years old.My ex remarried and would not pay that collection.So what should I do?

Comment: How much was the original debt? Is $3740 one month's rent?

Answer (score 2):

You have several choices. You seem to be aware your debt is valid and you do indeed owe the money. So, you can pay the full amount. You can attempt to settle for a portion of the amount owed. Or you can refuse to pay the debt.

You've already taken a substantial hit to your credit rating. Paying the full amount will stop any further degradation to your rating. Settling for a portion of the amount will be cheaper, but may result in an additional hit to your credit rating. Still, there's a good chance you could negotiate the debt down substantially and you may decide it is worthwhile. Or you can refuse to pay your debt. That may result in them taking you to court and will result in a substantial additional reduction to your credit rating.

You could try to take your ex-boyfriend to court. You'd need to show he lived there and you didn't, which would be challenging as you admit you did indeed stay there (albeit "from time to time"). Note, though, that you state, "I rented a apartment", meaning the debt belongs to you rather than to your boyfriend. So, unless you had a provable agreement with your boyfriend, the debt is yours alone and not his.

Note that this may seem dire, but credit ratings recover over time and many of us had to learn lessons the hard way. My lesson cost me much more than $3740. :)